# Update doesn't working using doctrine

Tags: doctrine

I want to update all my events having the same name by updating start and end dates ,

I have posted the question before but now I have changed some of the code but still not working ?

the code redirect to **app_event** route without updating !!

Where is the error ?

**Controller.php :**

```
public function updateEventsAction(Request $request )
{
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UpdateEventType');
    $form->handleRequest($request);
$event_name=$form[name]->getData();
$choosedName = $event_name->getName(); //get name from combobox


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Event')
    ;
    $events = $repository->findBy(
        array('name' => $choosedName) // array of events have same name choosen from combobox

    );
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

          //foreach event update start and end dates
            foreach ($events as $event) { 


            $event ->setStartDate($event ->getStartDate ());
            $event ->setEndDate($event ->getEndDate ());

                $em->persist($event);
                $em->flush();

            }

            return $this->redirectToRoute(‘app_event’);
    }
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Event:updateEvents.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**Event.html.twig**

```
{{ form_start(form}}

<div>
    <label for="name">Name of the event</label>
    <div >   {{ form_widget(form.name}}   </div>
</div>
<div >
    <label for="startDate ">Start date </label>
    <div >  {{ form_widget(form.startDate }}   </div>
</div>
<div> 
    <label for=" EndDate ">End date </label>
    <div>    {{ form_widget(form. endDate}}  </div>
</div>
    <div> 
        <button type="submit" ">Update</button>
    </div>
</div>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

**UpdateEventsType.php :**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add(' name ',EntityType::class,array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle: Event', 'choice_label'=>'name')   )
        ->add(' startDate ', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            // this is actually the default format for single_text
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
        ->add(' endDate ', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            // this is actually the default format for single_text
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
    ;   
}
```

**Update**

Now I have updated my code it seems a date format problem because after updating my code this is the error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE event SET startDate = '$ choosedStartDate ', endDate = '$ choosedEndDate ' WHERE name = ?' with params ["Events16"]:

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '$choosedDateDebut' for column startDate at row 1
```

This is the new code

```
public function updateEventsAction(Request $request )
{
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UpdateEventType');
    $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $event_name=$form['name']->getData();
            $choosedName = $event_name->getName();

            $choosedStartDate=$form[startDate]->getData();


            $choosedEndDate =$form[endDate]->getData();





            print_r("***********choosed Start date****************"); print_r($choosedStartDate);
            print_r("***********choosed end date****************"); print_r($choosedEndDate


            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $repository = $this
                ->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Event)
            ;
            $listevents= $repository->findBy(

                array('name' => $choosedName) // Critere
            );


           foreach ($listevents as $event) {

              $datestart_bd =$event->getDateDebut();

               print_r("Start date from database");
               print_r($datestart _bd);
            }

            $q = $em->createQuery('update AppBundle\Entity\Event e SET e.startDate =\'$choosedStartDate \' , e.endDate =\'$choosedEndDate \' WHERE e.name= ?1' );
            $q->setParameter(1, $choosedName);
            $q->execute();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_event');
    }
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Event:updateEvents.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**Update2**

Now the code work fine I am not using createQuery anymore

my code working:

```
public function updateEventsAction(Request $request )
{
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UpdateEventType');
    $form->handleRequest($request);
$event_name=$form[name]->getData();
$choosedName = $event_name->getName(); //get name from combobox
   $choosedStartDate=$form[‘startDate’]->getData();


            $choosedEndDate =$form[‘endDate’]->getData();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Event')
    ;
    $events = $repository->findBy(
        array('name' => $choosedName) // array of events have same name choosen from combobox

    );
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

          //foreach event update start and end dates
            foreach ($events as $event) { 


            $event ->setStartDate($choosedStartDate)
            $event ->setEndDate($choosedEndDate);

                $em->flush();

            }

            return $this->redirectToRoute(‘app_event’);
    }
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Event:updateEvents.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Just debug the output using some `dump($something)` to see whats wrong and take a look at the Symfony profiler to see if there is some error. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly to the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) directives.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting same dates to the events as you take them from database, when you probably want to set them from form.

Change this code fragment:

```
foreach ($events as $event) { 
        //$event_name variable holds your form data
        $event->setStartDate($event_name->getStartDate());
        $event->setEndDate($event_name->getEndDate());

        $em->persist($event);//note that you only need to persist new events, so this is unnecesarry
        $em->flush();//I'd recommend 'batch' flushes
}
```

More info on [batch processing](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html).